# UFW user rules...deleting a rule

Tags: bash, firewall, ufw

I need to open port 80 for certbot renewal, so I am trying to use pre-hook and post-hook features of certbot.  I can easily script adding a UFW rule to open port 80, but when I try to delete that rule (to close port 80 back up again), UFW insists on operating interactively, asking if I want to continue, so the rule deletion gets aborted.

How can I pass a "Y" to the "UFW delete rulenumber" command so it doesnt get aborted?  I have tried -y and /y but doesnt seem to work.

Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 BTW....

Comment: Rather than `delete`, which does require interaction, could you not simply `deny` all traffic to port 80? This would override the previous `allow` 

Answer (score 1):

Figgered it out.

```
yes | ufw delete 1
```

works.....